# FULL OUTER JOIN in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I just noticed `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not working in **Oracle**.

Other queries work fine but when I fire the query with Full outer join, it takes time and gets disconnected throwing the error.

**ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel**

*RIGHT OUTER JOIN* and *LEFT OUTER JOIN* works fine.

What can be alternative for the query below where I am using full outer join to get all records ?

```
select * from 
(
    select 
    FTM_OFFICE_ID,
    NVL(SUM(FTD_NRS_AMOUNT),0) as TOTAL 
    from FMS_TRANS_DTL 
    inner join FMS_TRANS_MST ON FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_TRANS_MST_ID = FMS_TRANS_DTL.FTD_TRANS_MST_ID 
    inner join FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG ON FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.FFVC_VOUCHER_ID = FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_VOUCHER_ID 
    where FFVC_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 and FTM_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
    and FTD_ACC_ID in (select distinct FDP_DHARAUTI_C_ACC_ID from FMS_DHARAUTI_PARAMETER where FDP_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67' )
    /*and FTD_ACC_ID in (591)*/
    group by FTM_OFFICE_ID 
) T1
full outer join
(
    select 
    FTM_OFFICE_ID,
    NVL(SUM(FTD_NRS_AMOUNT),0) as TOTAL 
    from FMS_TRANS_DTL 
    inner join FMS_TRANS_MST ON FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_TRANS_MST_ID = FMS_TRANS_DTL.FTD_TRANS_MST_ID 
    inner join FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG ON FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.FFVC_VOUCHER_ID = FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_VOUCHER_ID 
    where FFVC_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 and FTM_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
    /*and FTD_ACC_ID in (592)*/
    and FTD_ACC_ID in 
    (select distinct FDP_DHARAUTI_L_ACC_ID from FMS_DHARAUTI_PARAMETER where FDP_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67' )
    group by FTM_OFFICE_ID 
) T2
on T1.FTM_OFFICE_ID=T2.FTM_OFFICE_ID
/*
 The no. of rows that T1 can have can be different that no. of rows T2 can have. 
 Its not necessary any OFFICE_ID must have amount under any FTD_ACC_ID.
*/
```

Just noticed that if I remove the sub query in condition for `FTD_ACC_ID`, the query runs perfectly. Why ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Oracle supports full outer joins quite well.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : It says "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
" and I read somewhere Full Outer join is not supported by oracle.

Comment: Other queries work fine but when I fire the query with Full outer join, it takes time and gets disconnected throwing the error. "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
"

Comment: Then your problem lies elsewhere. What Oracle version is this? Are there any DB links / pipelined functions etc. involved?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : Its Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Prod.

Comment: @FlorinGhita : Other queries works fine. This query takes too much time and finally throws the error.

Comment: @hsuk did you check for any trace files in the user dumps area? there may very well be a user dump with an assoicated ORA-00600/7445 behind the scenes.

Comment: Please post also the execution plan of the query.

Comment: @DazzaL : I checked the alert.log and I got the following error:

**ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [_kkqtnloCbk+124] [PC:0x1DB818C] [ADDR:0xF5] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []**

Comment: @hsuk try disabling optimization of the outer join. `alter session set _optimizer_cost_based_transformation=off;` or in the sql as a hint `/*+ opt_param('_optimizer_cost_based_transformation', 'off')`. There are several ANSI bugs when using complex SQLs especially in the 10g initial release. If that does't solve it, then you should contact Oracle support assuming you have access, as there are several bugs listed that could match this error

Comment: Just noticed that if I remove the sub query in condition for `FTD_ACC_ID`, the query runs perfectly. Why ?

Comment: @hsuk because its a bug that your hitting. and given the Dump  parameters + your follow up, the likely bug is `BUG 4204383: ORA-7445[KKQTNLOCBK] USING QUERY WITH SUBQUERY AND FULL OUTER JOIN` (fixed 10.2.0.4 with backports available back to 10.2.0.2). The workaround i supplied if that bug is right should work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

workaround based on your query + followup comments is:

```
alter session set "_optimizer_cost_based_transformation"=off;
```

eg:

```
SQL> alter session set "_optimizer_cost_based_transformation"=off;

Session altered.
```

or in the sql as a hint

```
/*+ opt_param('_optimizer_cost_based_transformation', 'off')
```

eg

```
select /*+ opt_param('_optimizer_cost_based_transformation', 'off') */ * from 
(
    select FTM_OFFICE_ID,
```

you're possibly hitting bug:

```
BUG 4204383: ORA-7445[KKQTNLOCBK] USING QUERY WITH SUBQUERY AND FULL OUTER JOIN
```

which has patched available only on 10.2.0.2 onwards (fixed fully in 10.2.0.4).

Comment: I get **ORA-00972: identifier is too long** when I try to fire `alter session set_optimizer_cost_based_transformation=off;` and I could not understand the second one, _sql as a hint_ .

Comment: @hsuk you need to put it ain quotes. ie not `alter session set_optimizer_cost_based_transformation` but `alter session set "_optimizer_cost_based_transformation"` ie set is a seperate word and the name is in quotes.

Comment: @hsuk also see edit for how to put the hint version in the SQL.

Answer (score 4):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is supported just fine in Oracle.

The error you're experiencing sounds like an Oracle bug, or possible some form of corruption. You should find an error recorded in the `alert.log` whenever an ORA-03113 occurs.

Typically if you receive this error it's because the background oracle system process for that session has died (which is almost always due to an Oracle internal error).

This is a problem for your friendly local DBA.

Answer (score 2):

If indeed (for whatever reason) a full outer join doesn't work for you, use

```
-- all rows present in both t1 and t2
select * from t1 inner join t2
union all
-- all rows present in t1 but not in t2
select * from t1 left outer join t2 where t2.pk is null
union all
-- all rows present in t2 but not in t1
select * from t1 right outer join t2 where t1.pk is null
```

instead of

```
select * from t1 full outer join t2
```

This will return the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
But still I am trying to figure out why is full outer join not working. Seems like something is wrong with temp table spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
 SELECT 
    FTM_OFFICE_ID,
    NVL(SUM(FTD_NRS_AMOUNT),0) AS TOTAL 
    FROM FMS_TRANS_DTL 
    INNER JOIN FMS_TRANS_MST ON FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_TRANS_MST_ID = FMS_TRANS_DTL.FTD_TRANS_MST_ID 
    INNER JOIN FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG ON FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.FFVC_VOUCHER_ID = FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_VOUCHER_ID 
    WHERE FFVC_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 AND FTM_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
    AND FTD_ACC_ID IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT FDP_DHARAUTI_C_ACC_ID FROM FMS_DHARAUTI_PARAMETER WHERE FDP_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT FDP_DHARAUTI_L_ACC_ID FROM FMS_DHARAUTI_PARAMETER WHERE FDP_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'   
            )
    GROUP BY FTM_OFFICE_ID
```

Comment: :Thank you for your response but this is not what I need. This query gives the sum of amount according to OFFICE_ID on a single column. But I want the sum of amount according to OFFICE_ID on different columns. The total amount should be separated according to account head, FDP_DHARAUTI_C_ACC_ID and FDP_DHARAUTI_L_ACC_ID in terms of different OFFICE_ID. 
Anyway, I was asking if there is an alternative for FULL OUTER JOIN. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only thing different is separate totals for FTD_ACC_ID values of 105 and 110. One approach would be to use CASE statements to total those separately.

```
select 
FTM_OFFICE_ID,
NVL(SUM(CASE FTD_ACC_ID WHEN 105 THEN FTD_NRS_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END),0) as TOTAL_105,
NVL(SUM(CASE FTD_ACC_ID WHEN 110 THEN FTD_NRS_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END),0) as TOTAL_110,
 from FMS_TRANS_DTL 
inner join FMS_TRANS_MST ON FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_TRANS_MST_ID = FMS_TRANS_DTL.FTD_TRANS_MST_ID 
inner join FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG ON FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.FFVC_VOUCHER_ID = FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_VOUCHER_ID 
where FFVC_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 and FTM_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
and FTD_ACC_ID in (105,110)
group by FTM_OFFICE_ID
```

Comment: Oh well. For the question "is there an alternative to a full outer join" the answer is almost always yes but it depends on what your trying to achieve/retrieve with the overall query. There isn't a generic replace it with X answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN` in your query like this

```
select * from 
(

select 
FTM_OFFICE_ID,
NVL(SUM(FTD_NRS_AMOUNT),0) as TOTAL 
from FMS_TRANS_DTL 
inner join FMS_TRANS_MST ON FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_TRANS_MST_ID = FMS_TRANS_DTL.FTD_TRANS_MST_ID 
inner join FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG ON FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.FFVC_VOUCHER_ID = FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_VOUCHER_ID 
where FFVC_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 and FTM_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
and FTD_ACC_ID = 105
group by FTM_OFFICE_ID ) T1 union (select FTM_OFFICE_ID,
NVL(SUM(FTD_NRS_AMOUNT),0) as TOTAL 
from FMS_TRANS_DTL 
inner join FMS_TRANS_MST ON FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_TRANS_MST_ID = FMS_TRANS_DTL.FTD_TRANS_MST_ID 
inner join FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG ON FMS_FC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.FFVC_VOUCHER_ID = FMS_TRANS_MST.FTM_VOUCHER_ID 
where FFVC_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 and FTM_FISCAL_YEAR='2066/67'
and FTD_ACC_ID = 110
group by FTM_OFFICE_ID )T2
```

Comment: This won't work - you cannot have a ON clause in a UNION, and even if it were allowed, it wouldn't return the result required by the OP (your query would return 2 rows for a ftm_office_id that has both ftd_acc_id 105 and 110)